# Gtk3 Css button states

Tags: css, gtk3

I'm using gtk+-3.2.3 with css on Ubuntu natty. In the code below I have a button that starts out with a background color of green with blue text. When I hover over it the background color changes to red but the font color will not change to white as I've specified. Also when pressing and holding the button the background color changes to orange but the font color won't change to cyan that I've specified. Why is this happening? Is this the window manager over-riding my code?

```c
/*Compile with:
  gcc -Wall -o cssbutton2 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` cssbutton2.c
*/

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkCssProvider *provider;
  GdkDisplay *display;
  GdkScreen *screen;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 280, 200);
  g_signal_connect (GTK_WIDGET (window), "destroy",
                        G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label("CssButton");  
  gtk_widget_set_name (GTK_WIDGET(button), "mybutton");        
  gtk_widget_set_halign (GTK_WIDGET(button),GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_set_valign (GTK_WIDGET(button),GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(button), 200, 120);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),button); 

  provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
  display = gdk_display_get_default ();
  screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);                                                                                  
  gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider),    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

  gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (GTK_CSS_PROVIDER (provider),
                            " GtkWindow {\n"                          
                            "   background-color: tan;\n"
                            "}\n"
                            " GtkButton {\n"
                            "   -GtkWidget-focus-line-width: 0;\n"
                            "   border-radius: 15;\n"
                            "   font: Sans 23;\n"
                            "   color: #00008B;\n"                                       
                            "   background-color: green;\n"
                            "}\n"
                            " .button:hover {\n"
                            "   background-color: red;\n"
                            "   color: white;\n"
                            "}\n"
                            " .button:hover:active {\n"
                            "   background-color: orange;\n"
                            "   color: cyan;\n"
                            "}\n", -1, NULL);

  g_object_unref (provider);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: I could really use some help here, anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested this on Ubuntu 12.04 (gtk+ 3.4.2) and after adding `background-image: none;` to the `GtkButton` style definition, this works as you describe is the desired behavior.  Maybe just a bug in GTK that has since been fixed?

Comment: I believe your right but it so difficult to manually install gtk  that I don't want to risk messing up mine to check.

Answer (score 1):

you can reference the gtk css style grammar:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html

```
/*Compile with:
  gcc -Wall -o cssbutton2 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` cssbutton2.c
*/

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkCssProvider *provider;
  GdkDisplay *display;
  GdkScreen *screen;
  //GtkStyleContext *context;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 280, 200);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"CSSBUTTON");
  g_signal_connect (GTK_WIDGET (window), "destroy",
                        G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label("CssButton");  
  gtk_widget_set_name (GTK_WIDGET(button), "mybutton");        
  gtk_widget_set_halign (GTK_WIDGET(button),GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_set_valign (GTK_WIDGET(button),GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(button), 200, 120);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),button); 

  provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
  display = gdk_display_get_default ();
  screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);                                                                                  
   // context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(window);

  gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (provider,
                            "*{"
                            "color:green;"
                            "font-family:Monospace;"
                            "border:1px solid;"
                                 " }"       
                            " window {"                          
                            "   background-color: rgba(50,30,70,100);"
                            "   background-image:none;"
                            "}"
                            " button {"
                            "   border-radius: 15px;"
                            "   font: Sans 23;"
                            "   color: #00008B;"                                       
                            "   background-color: green;"
                            "   background-image:none;"
                            "}"
                            " button:hover {"
                            "   background-color: red;"
                            "   color: white;"
                            "}"
                            " button:hover:active {"
                            "   background-color: orange;"
                            "   color: cyan;"
                            "}", -1, NULL);

  gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
  g_object_unref (provider);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();
  return(0);
}
```